# (EMpirical Mode Decomposition+CNN) for time series forecasting

Tags: python, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network, forecasting

I'm currently working on a time series project, and I intend to employ the EMD+CNN technique for forecasting the output. Upon applying EMD to the training data, I obtained a total of 14 Intrinsic Mode Functions (IMFs). Consequently, I constructed my CNN neural network with dimensions (30100, 20, 14, 1), with 20 representing the window size. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to decompose the test data using EMD, as it produced only 11 IMFs. This inconsistency caused an error when trying to execute the CNN model.
Please note that I am utilizing the EMD-signal library in Python.

I have two questions: Is there a method to enforce a consistent number of IMFs during the EMD decomposition process? If not, is there an automated way to select the most significant IMFs?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import stft
from keras.models import Sequential
from PyEMD import EMD
spectrogrames = EMD(data2.values[:,-1],max_imf=10)
#spectrogram, res = ssa.get_imfs_and_residue()
print(spectrogrames.shape)
print(spectrogrames.shape)
spectrogrames = spectrogrames.T
print(spectrogrames.shape)
import pickle
import joblib
#print(train_size)
sf=data2.values
print(data2.shape)
# Concatenate the two NumPy arrays horizontally
spectrogram=spectrogrames[:,:11]
concatenated_array = np.hstack((spectrogram,sf))

# Convert the concatenated array back to a DataFrame with appropriate column names
df1 = pd.DataFrame(concatenated_array)
#training=sf[:train_size,:]
#testing=sf[train_size:,:]
print(df1.shape)
ahead=0
def signal_segmentation(dt,steps,ahead):
    end=0
    start=0
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(steps,dt.shape[0]):
        if i+ahead<dt.shape[0]:
            x.append(dt[i-steps:i,0:-1])
            y.append(dt[i+ahead,-1])
    return np.array(x),np.array(y)

from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsoluteError
from keras.regularizers import L1L2
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras import regularizers

n_hours=20
features=df1.shape[1]-1
#sf=data2.values

#train, test = train_test_split(sf, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
#print(train.shape)
#print(test.shape)
#x_train,y_train=signal_segmentation(train,n_hours,ahead)
#x_test,y_test=signal_segmentation(test,n_hours,ahead)
#print(x_train.shape)

#x_train, x_test = b[:train_size,:], b[train_size:,:]
#y_train, y_test = n[:train_size], n[train_size:]
#x_train=np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2]))
#x_test=np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2]))
#scaler = MinMaxScaler((0,1)).fit(x_train)
#x_train=scaler.transform(x_train)
#x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)
#print(x_train.shape)sss
#x_train=np.array(x_train, dtype=np.float64)
#y_train=np.array(y_train, dtype=np.float64)
#x_test=np.array(x_test, dtype=np.float64)
#y_test=np.array(y_test, dtype=np.float64)
#x_train=np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],n_hours,features))
#x_test=np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],n_hours,features))
#y_train=np.array(y_train).reshape((len(y_train),1))
#y_test=np.array(y_test).reshape((len(y_test),1))
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
print("steps:",n_hours)
x,y=signal_segmentation(df1.values,n_hours,ahead)
x_trainlstm, x_testlstm, y_trainlstm, y_testlstm = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)
```

Comment: An answer posted. If this does not answer your question, please edit the question to include some code and/or data as a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: I posted the code

Comment: Excellent. I think I see the problem. Answer below amended

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've successfully resolved one issue, but a new one has emerged. I divided my data into training and test sets and trained the model on the training data. I achieved an acceptable RMSE of 67 for the training set and 74 for the test set. However, when I assessed the model's performance on new data using a separate decomposition  EMD, I encountered a significantly higher RMSE of 300. This is puzzling because it can't be attributed to overfitting, as the model performed well on the test data previously. Can you provide any insights into this discrepancy?

Comment: To get a good answer I suggest asking this as a new question specifically with your code for train/test ad your new data processing. Questions with a lot of code are common. It is worth including a sample or pre processed data, a sample of processed data, and your expected output.

Comment: That being said, here is an article on your problem assuming no errors: https://machinelearningmastery.com/the-model-performance-mismatch-problem/

Comment: And when I have your problem, here are the errors I check: 1. Is the pre processing actually exactly the same? 2. Is the data actually roughly the same (check mean, std min, max etc). 3. Does the Machine Learning operation rely on randomness/stochastic processes: Need to run it multiple times (10) and figure out an average or something.

Answer (score 0):

#### Function amendments

From the [PyEMD docs](https://pyemd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/emd.html#PyEMD.EMD.emd), the EMD.emd() function has an argument max_imf (int, default=-1). The IMF number to which decomposition should be performed. Negative value means all. Note that your question shows you're passing data to the superior class **EMD()**, but the docs refer to a class method **EMD.emd()**

Your posted code:

```
from PyEMD import EMD
spectrogrames = EMD(data2.values[:,-1],max_imf=10)
```

Equivalent code in a documented example:

```
from PyEMD import EMD
s = np.random.random(100)
emd = EMD()
IMFs = emd.emd(s)
```

Your code amended to be like the example:

```
from PyEMD import EMD
decomposer = EMD()
spectrogrames = decomposer.emd(data2.values[:,-1],max_imf=10)
```

#### An alternative

'The most significant' Intrinsic Mode Function is possibly context dependant, as there are a number of ways to measure signals / waveforms. An obvious measure would be volume/amplitude - look at the second of the [documented examples](https://pyemd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) pictured below. IMF1 has an amplitude of around 0.2 after the initial edge effects, IMFs 2, 3, & 4 have amplitudes of respectively 10, 2, and 1.

[image: Example emf decomposition]

To automatically find the largest amplitude you could maybe look find the max/min values of the middle 50% of each IMF (to avoid edge effects) then select the largest n IMFs. Other things may be significant though - if a wave has a time period of 1 week/day/minute this may have significance in your context for example.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i tried to fix the max_imf but the function gives a number of IMFs greater than the given value.

Comment: Closing this off mentally - you were passing the argument to the top level class, when there was a class method that is able to control this. If my answer solved your original question, please consider marking it as a solution by clicking the tick.